# Date time parsing that accepts 05/05/1999 and 5/5/1999, etc

Tags: java, date, time, parsing

Is there a simple way to parse a date that may be in MM/DD/yyyy, or M/D/yyyy, or some combination? i.e. the zero is optional before a single digit day or month.

To do it manually, one could use:

```
String[] dateFields = dateString.split("/");
int month = Integer.parseInt(dateFields[0]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(dateFields[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(dateFields[2]);
```

And validate with:

```
dateString.matches("\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d\\d\\d\\d")
```

Is there a call to SimpleDateFormat or JodaTime that would handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my problem was using "MM/DD/yyyy" when I should have used "MM/dd/yyyy". Uppercase **D** is "Day in year", while lowercase **d** is "Day in month".

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(dateString);
```

Does the job. Also, "M/d/y" works interchangeably. A closer reading of the [SimpleDateFormat API Docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) reveals the following:

"For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields."

Answer (score 11):

Yep, use setLenient:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
df.setLenient(true);
System.out.println(df.parse("05/05/1999"));
System.out.println(df.parse("5/5/1999"));
```

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

Java 8 and later includes the java.time framework. This framework obsoletes the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes discussed in the other answers here.

The java.time.format package and its java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter class use pattern codes similar to that seen in the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228356/642706) by Ray Myers. While similar, they vary a bit. In particular they are strict about the number of repeated characters. If you say `MM`, then the month must have padded zero or else you get a [DateTimeParseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html). If the month number may or may not have a padding zero, simply use the single-character `M`.

In this example code, note how the month number of the input string has a padding zero while the day-of-month number does not. Both are handled by the single-character pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "M/d/yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parse ( "01/2/2015" , LocalDate :: from );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate );
```

> localDate: 2015-01-02