# java date parsing not working working for month

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to find the difference between two dates and I did the following:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
    String accessioned = "2017-04-27";
    System.out.println(date);

    try {
        date = format.parse(accessioned);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(date);

    Date now = new Date();

    long diff = now.getTime() - date.getTime();
    System.out.println(diff);

    if ((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) >= 30) {
        System.out.println("haha");
    }

 }

}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Fri Jul 21 14:23:59 CEST 2017
Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 CET 2017
15168239705
haha
```

The Problem is if I change the the String accessioned for e.g  to "2017-04-28" the date changes accordingly, same thing for year but whatever value I put for month, It always outputs January. For e.g in my code it should be April but the output says Jan.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the [javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): uppercase `D` is **day of year**, but what you need is **day of month**, which is represented by lowercase `d`

Comment: How hard did you search before asking? It seems you got a couple of valid answers, which is good, of course, I’m just thinking you might have got your answer even faster through your search engine. There are many questions and answers similar to this one.

Comment: Also helpful: [Date time parsing that accepts 05/05/1999 and 5/5/1999, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227608/date-time-parsing-that-accepts-05-05-1999-and-5-5-1999-etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `D` to `d` ([`SimpleDateFormat Doc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

- `D` is for day in year (1-365)
- `d` is for day in month (1-31)

Also you can now use `LocalDate` from Java8 more convenient to use [DateTimeFormatter Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) / [LocalDate Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

---

You apparently want to check if the difference of days is `>=30` between your date and now or not, so I'll propose another solution with `LocalDate` :

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-04-27", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
long daysDiff = localDate.until(LocalDate.now(), ChronoUnit.DAYS);

System.out.println(daysDiff);
if (daysDiff >= 30){
    System.out.println("haha");
}
```

EDIT : You need to use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate` to be able to use hour/minute/sec also

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-21T11:51:36Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: @azro thank you for the answer and the explanation. And about your suggestion for using LocalDate, it seems good but the string I need to parse will be in format "2017-04-21T11:51:36Z",  what should be the DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern for this?

Comment: Have you looked the doc a second ? not sure, I've edited with the answer, and think about accepting an answer when you'll be ok ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your date format: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD")`
As listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `M` is already a two-digit format - and `D` stands for "Day in year", not "Day in month", which is `d`.
Your format should look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d")
```

...which gives me:

```
Fri Jul 21 14:44:03 CEST 2017
Thu Apr 27 00:00:00 CEST 2017
7397043764
haha
```